# Cómo puedo mostrar los datos del último usuario modificado en Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Ejemplo:

Tengo una lista de datos con el siguiente formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al comienzo toda la lista está con la variable "confirmado = no", a medida que yo vaya apretando un botón, se irán cambiando los confirmados de un "no" a un "si". Por lo tanto, lo que espero es poder mostrar en mi App, la información del último usuario al que se le cambio el confirmado a un "si", en este caso quiero mostrar los datos del "usuario3", pero si el "usuario4" luego pasa a obtener un "confirmado = si", entonces quiero mostrar la información de él, que sería el último confirmado.

Cómo podría mostrar los datos del último usuario al que le he puesto "confirmado = si" y que se vaya actualizando cada vez que vaya confirmando nuevos usuarios?

Esto lo estoy trabajando con la Database de Firebase.

Algo como esto podría servir

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("z_ejemplo").orderByValue("si").limitToLast(1);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String nombre = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado/implementado?  ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Qué entiendes por modificado (creado o creado y/o actualizado)?

Comment: Eso es lo que tengo implementado. Estaba pensando en que algo como lo que agregue arriba me podría servir.

Comment: No estoy en mi pc, por eso aún no lo pruebo jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La aproximacion que se me habia ocurrido era usar el `childEventListener()` que devuelve `onChildChanged()` , el problema es que `onChildChanged()` nos avisa dentro de un nodo padre , en este caso `z_ejemplo` que un hijo cambio, pero no podemos saber cual de ellos cambio. Lo que podes hacer es agarrar en el momento que le pones `confirmado = si` a uno de esos nodos , obtener con `getKey()` el padre y saber que usuario es. De otra forma los listeners que usa Firebase no te van a servir para saber cual cambio, a no ser que agregues un `singleValueEventListener()` para cada uno de los usuarios, de esta forma solo preguntas

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists())
  String nombreUsuario = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```

de esta forma si podrias saber cuando uno en especifico cambia, pero calculo que tu proyecto crea los usuarios automaticamente y no podrias implementarlo.

Si lo que necesitas es como un sistema donde se solicite si el usuario esta confirmado para entrar, te sugiero que en el momento del ingreso, accedas al usuario en cuestion, me imagino algo como que el usuario se loguea, va a firebase, chequea si esta confirmado y luego ingresa. Para eso solo añades un `eventListener()` a ese solo usuario y te fijas si esta confirmado o no

EDIT: entendiendo un poco mas la pregunta podes hacer esto

```
databaseReference.child("z_ejemplo").orderByChild("confirmado").equalTo("si").limitToLast(1);
```

Donde .child("z_ejemplo") es el nodo a buscar el confirmado en cuestion, `.orderByChild("confirmado")` nos ordena por el hijo confirmado, `.equalTo("si")` nos dice que encuentre solo el child confirmado con el valor si y el `.limitToLast(1)` nos dice que solo nos traiga el ultimo elemento agregado

si queres obtener el valor de confirmacion del ultimo usuario

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference();
Query confirmaQuery = databaseReference.child("z_ejemplo").orderByChild("confirmado").equalTo("si").limitToLast(1);
confirmaQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String confirmado = dataSnapshot.child("confirmado").getValue().toString();
        String usuario = dataSnapshot.getKey();
       Log.e("Usuario : " , "" + usuario + "Confirmado: "+confirmado);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //manejamos error
    }
});
```

Comment: Recién estaba pensando trabajar con lo siguiente: databaseReference.child("z_ejemplo").orderByValue("si").limitToLast(1); Crees que eso podría servir para obtener el último "si" registrado? Aún no he podido probarlo porque no estoy en mi pc.

Comment: si, eso funcionaria perfecto, por que te traeria el ultimo agregado con el valor si, pero le deberias cambiar algo, ahi edito la respuesta

Comment: Gracias crack, eres de mucha ayuda. Éxito!

Comment: Ningun problema, me avisas como te fue y si surge alguna otra duda

Comment: ahi agregue algo mas si te interesa

Comment: Yo haría un *mini nodo*  (un único dato) con esta estructura: `{
 "ultimo": {
  "usuario": "fulano"
 }
}` cambiando el valor en usuario cada vez que haya un cambio y cuando necesite el último que cambió lo busco ahí. Conviene tener en cuenta [lo que dice Firebase sobre la forma de organizar los datos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/structure-data?hl=es-419). Cuando tengas millones de usuarios, no es lo mismo aplicar filtros a una estructura de millones de usuarios que ir a buscar un dato en un mini-nodo como este.